# How to install Linux alongside Windows 10 with a corrupted Grub?

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, grub, grub2

I had Windows 10 and Linux Mint in dual boot. I deleted from Windows 10, the partition related with Linux since it had some issues. Then after I reboot I see a grub window like below

[image]

I want to install again Linux, so if I try to install Linux again alongside with Windows 10 in dual boot, will that fix the grub menu or is needed to remove grub leaving only Windows MBR and then install Linux?

Currently I can access Windows since when I got this Grub window if I write `exit` then the system boots in Windows 10.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Grub consists of several pieces in different locations.  Deleting the partition left a stub of GRUB.  As long as you can boot the Linux live session or installation media, when you install Linux from there, it will replace the old GRUB with a complete working copy.

Comment: Thanks fixer1234. It worked like you said. Installing again Linux fixed GRUB.